# Java Recursively add to list

Tags: java

Everything seems fine, but there's an error with this line:

```
return new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(i, FACTORISATION(n/i)));
```

The error is: The constructor ArrayList(Arrays.asList(i), ArrayList) is undefined

I understand that the error says the the Array's asList method doesn't take an ArrayList, but then how can I add the items returned by FACTORISATION in the list? This recursion is really messing with my head

Comment: I don't think that error message is accurate, but your second return statement doesn't make sense. `Arrays.asList()` doesn't flatten its input. It just rolls everything up into a list. `Arrays.asList(i, FACTORISATION(n/i))` returns a `List<Object>`, which you can't pass into a `List<Integer>`.

Comment: An `ArrayList<Integer>` doesn't have room for a list. You'll have to create list separately and call `list.add(i);` then `list.addAll(FACTORISATION(n/i))`. Just a side note: `return...` in a `for` loop seems like a bug without any condition check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java isn't really a functional programming language, so writing functional code like this tends to be a little clunky.

You want something like this:

```
public static List<Integer> FACTORISATION(int n) {
    if (PRIME(n)) {
        // return a one-element array
        return Collections.singletonList(n);
    } else {
        // find a prime divisor, p
        for (int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
            List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>();
            newList.add(i);
            newList.addAll(FACTORISATION(n/i));
            return newList;
        }
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

Note I changed to return interface type `List<Integer>` and also to use `Collections.singletonList`.

If you can use Guava then try ImmutableList, which is a little more elegant.

```
public static List<Integer> FACTORISATION(int n) {
    if (PRIME(n)) {
        // return a one-element array
        return ImmutableList.of(n);
    } else {
        // find a prime divisor, p
        for (int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
            return new ImmutableList.Builder<Integer>()
                .add(i)
                .addAll(FACTORISATION(n/i))
                .build();
        }
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, but shouldn't a recursive method always return the method itself?

Comment: I think you're saying, shouldn't a recursive method `f` have, at the end, something like `return f(...)`? No, it doesn't have to. Yours doesn't either. It calls `FACTORISATION` on the last line, but that's not the last thing it does. After it calls `FACTORISATION` (assuming it could compile) it still has to call `asList` and build an `ArrayList` from the result. I've just split it up into separate lines in order to conform to the limitations of the `List` API.

Comment: Interesting, thank you! But is there a better way to append to a list in java or is this the best method for my case?

Comment: And by the way, your code doesn't have a default return statement

Comment: Neither does yours :-)

Comment: The canonical way to append to a `List` in Java is to call the `add` method. Unfortunately `add` returns a `boolean` not the original `List` so you can't chain calls to `add` and/or `addAll`, which means you usually need multiple statements to construct a `List`.

Comment: Thanks for the help Willis! And for the default return statement will returning null suffice, seeing as it will never hit it?

Comment: You don't want to return null. Remember, you're going go pass the return value of this function to `List.addAll`. You should return `Collections.emptyList()`.